# Using CompareText() and AdvPopupMenu

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I'm using C++Builder 10.3 with a VCL application for Windows.  I'm trying to identify a specific item in an AdvPopupMenu by looping through the Items Caption and comparing the Caption to my search text using CompareText(). The Captions have an '&' in the Caption text which I believe is part of the ShortCut feature. This seems to prevent a match when comparing the text.

I have tried setting up the menu items two ways to try and remove the '&'.

```
//--#1 Menu Setup-- 
TMenuItem *NewMenuItem;
NewMenuItem = new TMenuItem(MainForm->AdvPopupMenu1);
TShortCut sc2;
sc2 = TextToShortCut("(None)");
NewMenuItem->Caption = "Google";
NewMenuItem->ShortCut = sc2;


//--#2 Menu Setup-- 
TMenuItem *NewMenuItem;
NewMenuItem = new TMenuItem(MainForm->AdvPopupMenu1);
NewMenuItem->Caption = "Google";
NewMenuItem->ShortCut = NULL;
```

Below is my loop to search for the AdvPopupMenu item.

```
UnicodeString SearchFor = "Google";  
UnicodeString TestCaption;

for(int i=0; i<MainForm->AdvPopupMenu1->Items->Count; i++){
  TestCaption= MainForm->AdvPopupMenu1->Items->Items[i]->Caption;

  if(CompareText(SearchFor , TestCaption)==0 ){
    //This CompareText always fails
    //TestCaption looks like this "&Google" or this "G&oogle"
  }
}
```

How can I setup the AdvPopupMenu Caption to contain no '&' and make the CompareText work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&`s are important. Without these, keyboard users like myself will find your application more difficult to use.

I think your best solution is to use the `StripHotkey` function in the `Vcl.Menus` unit to remove the ampersand character before you pass the caption to `CompareText`. (In addition, instead of testing if `CompareText` returns `0`, it's better to use the `SameText` function.)

That is, don't attempt to create the menu items without the ampersand character, and don't try to remove it from the menu items. Only remove the character from the string you pass to the comparison function.

---

Also notice that the ampersand character is not related to the `ShortCut` property. The ampersand character makes the next character underlined in the menu item caption, telling the user than he or she can press that key to activate the menu item, but only when the menu is open. On the other hand, the `ShortCut` property adds a right-aligned text like `Ctrl+A` or `Shift+Ctrl+N` or `F2` to the menu item, and these shortcuts are available even when the menu isn't open. Hence, these are different features.

Comment: I was unaware of the StripHoykey function. That is exactly what I needed. You solution works. Thanks.